# I don't remember my Apple ID, but I do know the password

Tags: iphone, apple-id

I did a software update on my iPhone, and I cannot activate it as I don't remember the Apple ID but I do know the password. Is there any way to find my Apple ID? I only remember that the mail ended in `@ymail.com`, but I have never used that email.

I have tried to find my Apple ID at [iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid](https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid#!&section=appleid) but it did not help. Maybe you can?

Comment: If Apple can't help you, no-one else can.

Comment: There is no activation required after an iOS upgrade, but you are asked to re-login into iCloud. Usually you should be able to skip this step. Did you try that (and if yes, do you see your AppleID in Settings)?

Comment: You'll need to gain control of the Apple ID or reverse activation lock. Patrix is right, it's not normally locked post upgrade, but software cna fail in odd ways on occasion.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the same thing that if Apple can't help you no one can but what I would suggest you to call  Apple technical support and tell them your problem they should be able to help you out if it's your own phone they should be able to help you out as far you have access to that email account  that is associated with your iCloud account that you are trying to access. Like you said you have never used it but  I am  guessing you should have access to that email.